# Reading tabs in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to sscanf from a file. The pattern I am trying to match is the following
"%s\t%s\t%s\t%f"

Thing is that I am surprised because for an input like following:
Hello Hola Hallo 5.344434

it is reading all of the data properly...

Do you know why?

I was expecting it to be finding tabs like |---|---|---|---| not that only one space was matching.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way - `scanf` treat all white-space *identically* - they're used as delimiter, and just ignored. So if you really want to doing something with tab space, you should parse it yourself.

To parse, you need to read the whole line without any parsing, unlike *scanf*. So, you need to use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

```
FILE *fp = /* init.. */;
char buf[1024];
fgets(buf, 1024, fp);
// parse yourself!
```

Comment: `getline` is better than `fgets`, since it does not limit the length of the current line (except of course for resource exhaustion, i.e. out of memory)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes, but it's **not** standard C >o<

Answer (score 3):

The [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) reads:

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by
>   reading input up to the ﬁrst non-white-space character (which remains
>   unread), or until no more characters can be read.

In other words, a sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; as defined by `isspace()`) in the format string matches **any amount of white space in the input**.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) for `scanf`:

```
C string that contains a sequence of characters that control how characters extracted from the stream are treated:
Whitespace character: the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters
encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include
spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace). A single whitespace in the format
string validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream
(including none).
Non-whitespace character, except format specifier (%): Any character that is not
either a whitespace character (blank, newline or tab) or part of a format specifier
(which begin with a % character) causes the function to read the next character 
from the stream, compare it to this non-whitespace character and if it matches,
it is discarded and the function continues with the next character of format. If the
character does not match, the function fails, returning and leaving subsequent 
characters of the stream unread.
Format specifiers: A sequence formed by an initial percentage sign (%) indicates a
format specifier, which is used to specify the type and format of the data to be
retrieved from the stream and stored into the locations pointed by the additional
arguments.
```

You will notice that the whitespace characters get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Did you *carefully* read [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) documentation? You need to read the entire line using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) then parse that line "manually"!